Missing kerning with small caps and kpfonts-otf
Compare the output of this file with pdfTeX and LuaTeX. Is this a kerning issue with kpfonts-otf, or should I do something extra to turn on kerning for small caps?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifluatex}

\ifluatex
    \usepackage{kpfonts-otf}
\else
    \usepackage{kpfonts}
\fi

\begin{document}

VANITY.

\scshape vanity.

\end{document}

With pdfTeX:

With LuaTeX:


Apparently, the developer of kpfonts-otf forgot to add the kerning pair…

@egreg Okay, then I’ll notify the developer.

It looks like many kerning pairs regarding small and petites caps are missing or wrong.  I'll try to fix this issue but don't expect anything soon.
